# Invalid object name 'dbo.UserProfile'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I have a few web applications that share a Membership database.  I use a `SimpleMembershipProvider`.  I added columns `Firstname` and `Lastname` in the `UserProfile` table.  I need the Firstname and Lastname information in one of the applications.  I have a helper method that populate the information into SuggestionVM view model.

```
private SuggestionVM PopulateSuggestionVM(Suggestion suggestion)
{
    UsersContext userContext = new UsersContext();
    var user = userContext.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == suggestion.UserId);
    var name = "";

    if (user != null)
    {
        name = user.Firstname + " " + user.Lastname;
    }

    SuggestionVM suggestionvm = new SuggestionVM()
    {
        Id = suggestion.Id,
        Title = suggestion.Title,
        Comment = suggestion.Comment,
        UserId = suggestion.UserId,
        Name = name,
        IsAnynomous = (suggestion.UserId == null) ? true : false,
        SubmittedDate = suggestion.SubmittedDate
    };

    return suggestionvm;
}
```

The method above is called in the Index method of Suggestion controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    List<SuggestionVM> suggestionvms = new List<SuggestionVM>();
    var suggestions = db.Suggestions.ToList();

    foreach(var suggestion in suggestions)
    {
        SuggestionVM suggestionvm = PopulateSuggestionVM(suggestion);
        suggestionvms.Add(suggestionvm);
    }

    return View(suggestionvms);
}
```

Whenever I run it, I get the error below:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.UserProfile'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.UserProfile'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: There is no such table name `UserProfile` on your database that is pointed by the connection string.

Comment: I have 2 connection strings, one the `defaultConnection` that point to the application db, another is `membershipConnection` that points to Membership db.  The `dbo.UserProfile` exists in the `membershipConnection` since it's one of the default tables for `SimpleMembershipProvider`.